# Finding an equation of a plane passing through the origin with cylinder such that the intersection is a circle.

Tags: calculus, quadrics

I have the following question here...

> Find an equation of a plane through the origin such that the intersection between the plane and the elliptical cylinder $\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$ is a circle.

Wouldn't this simply just be $ax+by=0$??? The plane has to pass the origin, so $d=0$ and since the plane has to be perpendicular to the cylinder to get circular cross section, we get that $z=0$. This results in $ax+by=0$. I feel like this is too simple and I am overlooking something.

Comment: Take $a=1, b=1$. Then the plane $x+y=0$ intersects the cylinder in two lines. And $z=0$ in a circle.

Comment: "the plane has to be perpendicular to the cylinder": no. And even if it were, its equation would be $z=0$, not $ax+by=0$.

Answer (score 3):

If for instance $a\ge b$, take a plane $$z=ky.$$ The intersection with your cylinder will be an ellipse, whose semi-axes $a$ and
$b\sqrt{1+k^2}$ are equal iff $$k=\pm \frac{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}b.$$